# How do Samsung S8 phones modify the app icon for the Always On screen?

Tags: android

My app icon is not appearing correctly on Samsung S8 phones when the “Always On” display is active. The icon is there, but it appears very, very dark. It does, however, work properly on S9 phones. And the app icon appears properly everywhere else on the Samsung S8. It is only the S8 "Always On" screen that isn't working. So may I ask how Samsung S8 phones sources and modifies the app icon for the "Always On" screen?